# Is there anyway to access root on iPhone using NSFileManager?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I was trying to access the root directory and list the contents of it but I got 0 folders listed there. I s there anyway to access it for instance to query the SMS.db under root/SMS folder.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without a jailbroken iPhone. Applications are segregated.